# Error response ''NoneType' object is not iterable' while scraping website using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to web-scraping using scrapy. I am trying to scrape a website (Please refer to urls in the code).
From the website ,i am trying to scrap the information's under the 'Intimation For%Month%%Year% ' table and transfer the data to json file.

> I am getting an error as "'NoneType' object is not iterable",while executing the command:
>
> > scrapy crawl quotes -o quotes.json

Code:

```
import scrapy
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "quotes"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
       'http://www.narakkalkuries.com/intimation.html#i'
    ]

def parse(self, response):
  for check in response.xpath('//table[@class="MsoTableGrid"]'):
    yield{
           'data':check.xpath('//table[@class="MsoTableGrid"]/tr/td/p/b//text()').extract_first()
         }
```

Problem:
In the website,all the intimation data is stored under table with same name **table@class="MsoTableGrid"**.

Option's i tried to extract the data

> Option1
>
> > `response.xpath('//table[@class="MsoTableGrid"]').extract()`
> >
> > > Return all the data
>
> Option2
>
> > `response.xpath('//table[@class="MsoTableGrid"]/tr[i]/td/p/b').extract()`
> >
> > > Return few of the vertical column
>
> Option3
>
> > `response.xpath('//table[@class="MsoTableGrid"]/tr/td/p/b//text()').extract()[1]`
> >
> > > Return first element from the whole data

Question:

- While using Option3,is it possible to know the if the element returned is a string or not?
- While using Option3,is it possible to know the entire range of data returned,so that we can traverse through each returned element ?
- How to fix the error "NoneType' object is not iterable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "quotes"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
       'http://www.narakkalkuries.com/intimation.html#i'
    ]

    # Here you need to yield the scrapy.Request
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url)

def parse(self, response):
  for check in response.xpath('//table[@class="MsoTableGrid"]'):
    yield{
           'data':check.xpath('//table[@class="MsoTableGrid"]/tr/td/p/b//text()').extract_first()
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to that `start_requests` is expected to be a generator of `scrapy.Request` objects. Your `start_requests` does not yield anything:

```
def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
       'http://www.narakkalkuries.com/intimation.html#i'
    ]
```

To fix that either yield urls one by one in your `start_requests` method:

```
def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
       'http://www.narakkalkuries.com/intimation.html#i'
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield Requst(url)
```

Or use default `start_requests` method that is inherited from `scrapy.Spider` just by setting `start_urls` class attribute:

```
import scrapy
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.narakkalkuries.com/intimation.html#i'
    ]
```